How to extends PostgreSQL dialect to add support for some custom column type? No type mapping for org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes code: 1111 (OTHER)
I am writing integration tests and encountered with a problem. When I launch the app, everything works fine. However, when running the tests, I get an exception:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to determine SQL type name for
column 'id' of table 'some_table' because there is no type mapping for
org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes code: 1111 (OTHER)

Some entity uses  the following mapping for identifiers:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Type(value = SomeUUIDType.class, parameters = @Parameter(name = "column", value = "id"))
private UUID id;

Class SomeUUIDType just extends MutableType from Hypersistence and was added for some reasons (I don't know why - it's just there):
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.MutableType;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.IndexedConsumer;
import org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.JdbcMapping;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDJavaType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.UUIDJdbcType;
import org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType;
import org.hibernate.usertype.ParameterizedType;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SomeUUIDType extends MutableType<UUID, UUIDJdbcType, UUIDJavaType> implements ParameterizedType, EnhancedUserType<UUID> {

    public SomeUUIDType() {
        super(UUID.class, UUIDJdbcType.INSTANCE, UUIDJavaType.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID fromStringValue(CharSequence seq) throws HibernateException {
        return UUID.fromString(seq.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public <X, Y> int forEachDisassembledJdbcValue(
            Object value,
            int offset,
            X x,
            Y y,
            JdbcValuesBiConsumer<X, Y> consumer,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session
    ) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int forEachJdbcType(int offset, IndexedConsumer<JdbcMapping> indexedConsumer) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues(Properties params) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlLiteral(UUID value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(UUID value) throws HibernateException {
        return value.toString();
    }
}

I write some elementary tests to start with. Here I create an entity and try to save it:
@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "some.package")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("/test-application.properties")
public class SomeTest {

    @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> testContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest");

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;


    @DynamicPropertySource
    private static void overrideProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", testContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", testContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", testContainer::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.driverClassName", testContainer::getDriverClassName);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertTrue(testContainer.isCreated());
        assertTrue(testContainer.isRunning());

        assertNotNull(context);
        assertNotNull(em);

        SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
        entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        em.persistAndFlush(entity);
    }
}

My test-application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

pom.xml includes the following dependencies:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

I searched for information and found that it is necessary to define a custom dialect. Something like this:
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    @Override
    protected void registerColumnTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.registerColumnTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        
        DdlTypeRegistry ddlTypeRegistry = typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getDdlTypeRegistry();        
        ddlTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(Types.OTHER, ....);
    }
}

Then just plug it in:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=some.package.CustomPostgreSQLDialect

But what exactly I need to override here is unclear to me. And is that the reason?
I actually just write tests and can't change existing code. I suppose it is possible to configure a custom dialect to prevent an exception.

@UuidGenerator came with Hibernate 6, hence you can clean up a little by just using @Id @UuidGenerator BR

I would be glad of course, but I can't change existing code) in the future I'll try to do as you recommend, thank you

My bad, TL;DR :-) There are 4 versions of hypersistence-utils, have you checked that you're using the correct one?

Yes, it works with version 60. As far as I understand, I need to register this type in my test environment somehow. For that, I need to extends the dialect class somehow and specify this new custom class in the properties file. Maybe I'm wrong)

Can you update your question with the implementation of SomeUUIDType so I can implement a few tests?

Of course, I will be grateful. I added the code.

Spring 3.2.1 is using Hibernate 6.4, and SomeUUIDType needs hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.9.0 to compile on my computer. Am I overlooking something?

Oh, sorry, you're absolutely right, I was wrong. Really hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.9.0 is used..

After looking into this, it seems like issue is related to letting Hibernate create the table. With Flyway, there are no errors.
I had some difficulties with your test class, hence I show all of my code used in tests.
src/test/resources/db/migration/V1__Create_Tables.sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE some_entity
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
);

Dependencies
With newer versions of Spring Boot, use testRuntimeOnly("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql")
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.9.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    testImplementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
}

application-test.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
    username: test
    password: test
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration

PostgresTestContainerConfig
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

@TestConfiguration
public class PostgresTestContainerConfig {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    public PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer() {
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15-alpine");
    }
}

SomeEntityRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface SomeEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeEntity, UUID> { }

SomeTest
replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE can be removed with Spring Boot 3.4.0.
import no.myapp.database.PostgresTestContainerConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import(PostgresTestContainerConfig.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    SomeEntityRepository sut;

    @Test
    void testSave() {
        SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
        sut.save(someEntity);

        assertEquals(1, getItemCountInDb());
    }

    long getItemCountInDb() {
        return (long) em.getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SomeEntity")
                .getSingleResult();
    }
}


Excellent! Thank you for sharing your experience!
